# Server generated passwords

Tags: security, passwords

Is it more secure to have a server randomly generate passwords for users upon registration instead of letting users type their own passwords? Of course, those passwords would be bcrypt-ed.

I reckon if someone breaks into your website database, passwords retrieved would be useless outside of your website, unless the user starts using your randomly generated password for other purposes, which I think is 100% unlikely.

Hence you don't have to worry about malicious users using stolen password to break into user's email, bank account or whatever else they might have on the web, unless I'm missing something out.

Are there risks associated with server generated passwords?

Apologies for bad English.

Comment: See [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/26067/8340).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt rely on randomness. The key is to **never** store passwords. You store hashes of passwords and the salts used to generate those. You should use a cryptographically safe hashing algorithm such as pbkdf2 or bcrypt. Take a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage) post.
What is your plan in regards to dealing out random passwords? Send it to the registered email address?
I believe many would prefer using their own passwords. Keep in mind that there people who do not use keystores (such as chromes password manager) could probably be desuaded from using your website if they have to remember a randomly generated one.

Comment: In general @LuqJensen is correct. The potential problem with user generated passwords is they can be really bad. If a logged-in user can access other than their own information this can be a security problem. Users may not like this practice unless they understand it is protecting them. Personally I will use horrible passwords on sites that don't matter *to me* and where I won't have an unacceptable liability.

Comment: the answer to that is to force some requirements onto the password, of course it may still be bad but it is less likely.. Eg. given a password with a length of at least 8 and no repeated characters and uppercase letters and numbers, maybe even a special character. For the other part yes it does somewhat depend on the users task and privileges, but it should be solvable with an authorization implementation

Comment: Let's say you are running a site with screeners where every user has access to the movies. Also consider the [lists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords) of popular passwords along with the password attack programs available for an attacker. Consider that if *any user* is compromised all content is available. The chances that all 1000+ users will have passwords that are "good enough" is slim to non-existent.

Comment: An example I have seen used: two words chosen from a medical dictionary at random (most are really weird) joined by a non-AN character. They are pronounceable. Other than that vet against the lists mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My biggest area of concern is "malicious users downloading my database > unlocking hashed passwords > using those passwords to break into their email/bank account/etc"

Comment: @LuqJensen I was thinking about sending the server generated password to their email address, yes. And yeah, I intend to use bcrypt for all stored passwords. I might even bcrypt e-mail addresses.

Comment: @zaph The thing is, a server generated password can never be as bad as some user generated passwords often happen to be. And I don't wanna force them to use symbols and numbers they'll never remember either.

Comment: If the biggest area of concern is "malicious users downloading my database" the first thing you need to do is secure the server. 2-factor authentication with a well controlled 2nd factor. Rate limit failed attempts and downloads, you will see thousands of attempts a couple of minutes.. Log and review failed attempts. You are going to have to keep the email addresses for password resets.

Comment: The email addresses cannot be hashed indeed.